# SELECT con símbolos de número ORACLE PLSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, sql, select, plsql

¡Hola!

¿Alguien sabe qué función tienen los símbolos numéricos en esta consulta? 
En #V_LOTE" y "NUM_GPOS". Estoy trabajando con PLSQL ORACLE 12C.

```
> select #V_LOTE# + decode(floor(rownum/ceil(count(1)
> over()/#NUM_GPOS#)),    
>                                      #NUM_GPOS#,    
>                                      #NUM_GPOS# - 1,    
>                                      floor(rownum/ceil(count(1) over()/#NUM_GPOS#))
>                                 ) lote,    
>     row_id from (    
>                 select rowid row_id    
>                 from t_work partition (SP123)    
>                 where estatus  = 'SIN_PROCESAR';    
>                 );
```

¡Gracias!

Comment: Es NO es la sintáxis de Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Son expresiones inválidas en Oracle:

> Un identificador no-entrecomillado debe comenzar con un caracter alfabético

No es raro que en determinadas circunstancias al copiar código se sustituyan caracteres especiales por otros. En este caso supongo que se reemplaza `#` por `"`.

Answer (score -1):

El símbolo # funciona como un comodín. El mismo reemplaza cualquier número del 0 al 9.

En ese caso, la consulta retornaría datos siempre y cuando tuvieras registros donde la 
columna 'suboperacion' estuviera compuesta de UN numero antes del literal SUBOPERACION 
y UN numero después del mismo.

Ejemplo: 0SUBOPERACION1